# Can I join Master's in CS in Oxford, Mit, University of Edinburgh or similar colleges as a ECE student from India?

Tags: masters, engineering, enrollment

I looked into the colleges given above and under requirements it says that electrical engineers would be eligible for CS degrees.

I'm going to study ECE as my undergraduate course. Would that also be enough to enroll into those colleges?

Comment: You might need to clarify. Those universities get more applicants than they can teach and are therefore competitive to get in to.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Yes, I understand. But now, I just want to know if I met the basic eligibility to study there. For example, I can't join in the CS master's degree in those colleges if I took a bachelors in gender studies right? That is my question. Just as far as degrees go would a Electronics and communications degree in undergraduate AKA ECE not be entirely rejected there?

Comment: *if I met the basic eligibility to study there* --- This is often a non-issue for US universities, where eligibility is almost never a rigid set of minimum requirements but rather for the most part admission is based on the evidence you can present in your application that you have the appropriate background to begin (content knowledge) and the appropriate potential to complete the degree program (ability and drive), and (roughly speaking) your overall ranking in these aspects is not less than the number of students they can admit. **(continued)**

Comment: Since @Alexander Woo has already mentioned Witten (who I had just now written about, then shortly afterwards I saw Woo's comment below, so I've deleted what I said), I'll give another example. When I was an undergraduate a friend of mine, who was enrolled with me in several of the advanced undergraduate and beginning graduate courses in physics that I took, had an undergraduate degree in classics from Princeton. He got a Masters in physics where I was an undergraduate, then he obtained his Ph.D. in physics at another university.

Comment: **Correction** (if anyone cares): The person I knew didn't get his undergraduate degree in classics from Princeton, [he got it from UNC](https://classics.unc.edu/undergraduate-2/students-past-and-present/mark-suskin/), and he also had a minor in physics. However, he did spend a couple of years at Princeton as a graduate student in classics before doing some (non-degree?) coursework in physics. Notwithstanding his higher prestige, Witten is a much stronger example. He not only majored in history, but his minor was linguistics, and then he spent a couple of years with journalism and politics.

Answer (score 4):

For each available seat in their Masters program, MIT gets around a dozen applicants, all eligible under their published requirements.  This means they are accepting less than 10% of qualified applicants.  They get to pick the best of the applicants.

Keep in mind that many qualified applicants don't even bother applying to MIT because they know they are not competitive.

If you are going to an average college in India, you realistically need to be among the top 1% of students to be accepted to MIT.  This will be attested to not only by your marks but also by the recommendations of your professors based on their assessment of your abilities, not just in your studies but also in any research you might do.

Comment: I understand that it is incredibly difficult to join MIT. I'd just like to know ignoring everything else, if I take ECE as my undergraduate would I meet their basic entry requirements? Or would I be rejected as that is a study which is far away from CS so it would not be considered when I want to take masters.

Comment: Ed Witten (the Fields Medal winner) studied History as an undergraduate before doing an Masters in Applied Mathematics at Princeton (and then a PhD in Physics).  The US system is amazingly flexible for exceptionally talented people.  It's misleading to think in terms of basic entry requirements.  Rather, the farther away you are from the ideal background, the more you have to demonstrate your potential in other ways, to the extent that someone who did their undergraduate degree in Gender Studies but somehow showed exceptional promise in Computer Science could be admitted.

Answer (score 0):

Any engineering degrees students can study computer science specialization or non-specialization masters. But computer engineers can't study Electrical Engineering in masters specially specialization subjects. You should show the syllabus that you studied in your ECE degree. We need to see if it was more like Computer Engineering or EEE degree.

Getting entry into them is tough though. Unless you're from IITs in India. But it doesn't matter because anywhere in the west, there's good education than in India.

Comment: Can you clarify your second sentence? As it is, it sounds like you're saying that MIT, Oxford, Edinburgh, and all similar schools have a blanket policy that computer engineers can't do a master's in EE, which I seriously doubt is the case.

Comment: You could study some or none of EE. Like embedded system,Telecom, VLSI, PLCs, DSP,power electronics but no pure EE. EE vs ECE/CoE vs Electronics+Communication is different in India. EE deals with hydropower, high voltage engineering, house wiring designs, whereas ECE deals with 5V components. CoE and ECE could differ according to college, but are generally similar. Elex+Comx is different from ECE, it doesn't contain many computer science core subjects(it does contain OS, Computer Network...).1/2

Comment: If you're a EE grad, 100% you can study CS(or any specialization like AI, data science etc) in MS, but if you're CoE/ECE student, it's very less likely you'll get to study everything in EE(3/3 below). Although unis don't tell explicitly, students should take it as a rule of thumb that there chances to study EE as CoE/ECE grad is pretty low. (EE as per the Indian definition of EE).  ECE students can very well study EEE because if they studied 2 semesters more, they can get EEE degree as well in India. So, maybe some preriqusites need to be learnt, like 20 EE subjects haha. It's impossible.

Comment: 3/3 Only few selected CoE graduates will be able to study EE because EE is tougher and CS is very easy.